# Error with Image field

Tags: php

This script is giving error if name field and file field is same. That if I want to upload file with `a.jpg` and name field is also `a` than its giving error of rename. Let me know to remove this problem and help to remove previous file.

```
$username=$name ;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"],"albumpic/".$_FILES["pic"]["name"]);
$ext=substr($_FILES["pic"]["name"],strpos($_FILES["pic"]["name"],".")); 
if(file_exists("albumpic/$username$ext"))   { unlink("albumpic/$username$ext"); }

rename( "albumpic/".$_FILES["pic"]["name"],"albumpic/$username$ext");

$newphoto="$username$ext";
//var_dump($photo);
$err="";
```

Comment: Please post your form as well as the exact error message you get from PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is horribly bad code. You first move the user-provided file, which overwrites anything that was there before. You extract the file's extension in an unreliable manner (think of what happens if someone uploads `mypic.jpg.exe`). You then rename the uploaded file AFTER it's possibly trashed something what was there before.

Consider the case that you've got users "Joe" and "Fred" with profile pictures "joe.jpg" and "fred.jpg". What if Fred uploads a new profile picture called "joe.jpg". Your system will destroy Joe's image.

Try this instead:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['pic']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (file_exists("albumpic/$username$ext")) {
    unlink("albumpic/$username$ext");
}

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], "albumpic/$username$ext")) {
   die("Unable to move user $username's picture to album directory");
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function path_info() in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\shadaab\album_action.php on line 70`

Comment: Woops, sorry, typo on my part. should be `pathinfo` without the `_`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Please help with last question.. Scripting is going well. But it consistently increase my folder space that is if file with that name is not exist than of course script adds new pic. But at same how can I remove previous associated pic.

Comment: That's what the `file_exists()` thing is supposed to handle. If it's not removing the old files, check that the file_exists AND unlink calls are doing what they're supposed to.